# Does taxiing in London City (LCY) happen on the runway?

Tags: taxiing, taxiways

I recently had a ride to LCY (London City). Awesome, by the way. They have only one runway (09/27) and no apparent taxiways.

[image]
([Source: Google Maps](https://www.google.de/maps/@51.5047211,0.0545771,1018m/data=!3m1!1e3))

After landing, how do the aircraft get from the runway to the terminal? Do they just perform a U-turn on the (end of the) the runway and taxi back to the terminals?

Comment: Nomenclature: taxiing down the runway in the opposite direction of takeoffs/landings is known as a back-taxi.

Comment: Probably, since there doesn’t appear to be any other option.  Since you were just there though, weren’t you able to observe this directly yourself?  Or I guess you didn’t think about it at the time and only noticed when looking at the overhead image later...

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is no possible alternative to taxiing back along the runway. What else could you possibly even imagine as an alternative?

Comment: Why the down vote? Question whose answer is obvious to many may not be obvious to others.

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/20903/62) isn't exactly a dupe, but it gives a lot of relevant information

Comment: @Jimmy The asker is aware that taxiing down the runway is a possibility. There are no other conceivable possibilities.

Comment: The photo clearly shows a short bit of taxiway south of the runway 27 threshold. There seems to be enough of it that at busy times you could convoy three or four departing aircraft out to it along the runway at once, and have the latter of them wait out to the side while the ones in front take off. And close-together arrivals on runway 09 could do the opposite.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Certainly there's an alternative to back taxiing. If you're landing on 09, when you get to the 27 end, you pull off on the little taxiway there, hop on an awaiting barge and float back to the terminal area. Obvious! ;)

Comment: @DavidRicherby There are lots of conceivable alternatives. Maybe landing is only permitted on 27, or maybe aircraft are required to taxi in the grass, or maybe this airport is only open to aircraft that are capable of vertical takeoff. It's not necessarily obvious to everyone that aircraft backtaxi here on a regular basis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer the title question, yes.

There are nice timelapse videos for EGLC/LCY on YouTube, if you want to see it in action. ([Example](https://youtu.be/gSJ2caxJbrY).)

As for the actual operation at the airport, below is the official chart and textual data via the [UK AIP](http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/public/index.php%3Foption=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=92&Itemid=141.html):

> 6 USE OF RUNWAYS
>
> b) Minimum Runway Occupancy Time - Arriving Aircraft.
>
> 1. Pilots are reminded that prompt exit from the runway enables ATC to apply minimum spacing on final approach that will achieve maximum runway utilisation and will minimise the occurrence of 'go-arounds'.
> 2. When landing on Runway 09 pilots **should commence back-track as soon as practicable** and exit via Hold Echo unless otherwise instructed by ATC. Any aircraft that continues landing roll beyond Hold Kilo may infringe the [ILS critical area](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24657/14897).
> 3. When landing on Runway 27 A318 and CS100 pilots should plan to exit at Hold Delta (after a back-track if required). A318 and CS100 aircraft are not permitted to exit via Holds Charlie, Bravo, or Alpha. All other aircraft types may use any Hold to exit the runway except Hold Echo which shall only be used when specifically instructed by ATC. Pilots should be aware that use of Hold Alpha will increase Runway Occupancy Time.
> 4. Pilots expecting to use the full runway length to stop (e.g. due aircraft weight/meteorological conditions) are requested to inform Thames Radar on first contact.

(Bold emphasis mine.)

The short version (runway 9): backtrack [on the runway] to vacate as soon as possible (example [from cockpit](https://youtu.be/PMiN2r-ippI?t=135)) using the *specified* exits even if other exits may seem to be available, and if you need full runway length, notify the approach controller (Thames Radar).

(If the pilot does need full length, the approach controller needs to know to add extra spacing for the plane behind.)

For the exits mentioned in the text, reference the chart below:

[image]

Comment: Can a smaller plane (not sure of the precise value of "smaller") use `Twy F Stub` as a turnaround point to expedite the turnaround and minimize the back taxi time?

Comment: @FreeMan: Sorry not following. The stub is marked X. It's right next to a circular pad made for that purpose. See quoted points 2 and 4. Note: even without the pad near the stub, an A318 (largest plane LCY handles) can [manage a 180](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obrhQ.png) on that 30 m wide runway, so a smaller plane would need even less width.

Comment: I'm not a pilot, so I'm not familiar with all runway chart markings - in particular the significance of the `X` marking. I presume though, based on your comment, that's exactly what Taxiway F Stub is for? Ooohhh... the `X` means Taxiway `F` is closed (possibly stubbed out for future development), but all planes should stop as quickly as possible, execute a 180° turn ASAP, then back taxi and vacate the runway at Echo

Comment: @FreeMan: The circular pad I mentioned would speed up the procedure. Here it is via [Google Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywdWT.png). Also worth mentioning, UK's prevailing winds is from the west, so runway 27 operations are more common, and here point 3 comes in, where Echo is typically not used for vacating (as it is used by the planes waiting to backtrack for a runway 27 departure).

Comment: OK, so the circular pad _could_ be used for turnarounds for those landing 09 ("prevailing" doesn't mean "always" ;) but isn't 100% necessary. Interesting that those A318/CS100 landing 27 need to make the 135° turn to Delta instead of the easier 90°  to Charlie or the eased 90° to Bravo. Sorry for derailing and taking this somewhat OT.

Comment: @FreeMan: "[M]ore common" is not always, I don't know why you put *always* in quotation marks :-) Point being, the airport is designed (ramp location) with the most common operation in mind. Also C, B, and A are narrow, which explains why the big types use D.

Comment: Ah! Didn't note the width difference. Being nagged to move to chat now, so I'll sign off. Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the timelapse videos. I like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Veufut64nPM) and at [03:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Veufut64nPM&t=3m30s) we can see a plane which I think is an A319 doing a 180° turn right on the runway _between_ exits Delta and Echo and then vacates via Echo. Not sure if it's an A319 but it looks shorter and "thicker" than all those Embraers and somehow "airbussy".

Comment: @PerlDuck: Super find  That's an Airbus A318 using Delta as point 3 says (due to its size compared to the other smaller LCY traffic – other exits are narrower). And here's runway 09 from the [cockpit of a jet](https://youtu.be/me0KVv_nTXI?t=83).

Comment: Yes, A318 is right. The German Wiki lists the [allowed aircraft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_City_Airport#Zugelassene_Flugzeuge) for LCY and A319 is not listed. I mixed that up. But I still think he uses Echo, not Delta in the video (contrary to what point 3 suggests).

Comment: @PerlDuck: You're right, that's Echo – still, Echo is not in the *not permitted* list. And point 3 permits Echo if ATC specifies it.

Comment: @PerlDuck: From the [2016] video I linked [in the answer](https://youtu.be/PMiN2r-ippI?t=135), the pilot uses what seems to be Echo on the chart, but the sign (and text) say Delta. (That's why I confused them.) Update: [Mystery solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amwEY.png), the current D is a new taxiway.

Comment: @ymb1  Yes, that confused me as well. Thank you for clarifiying that. Nowadays LCY has exits A-E but at the time the video was shot (2015) it was A-D. They built a new exit between the old C and D which became the new D and the old D became E. I tried to figure out when this took place but couldn't find a source. However. Fact is: the A318 vacates at the exit closest to the water.

Answer (score 1):

Taxiing back to the other end is a "backtrack".  At a controlled airport like that, the backtrack would need a clearance.

When you land at London City, you will roll out and turn off onto that little turnaround bay, where you are "clear of the active" and you would then need a backtrack clearance to return to the other end.

It would depend on the traffic level.  If you landed and someone was right behind you, you might need to wait for the other a/c to roll past and then you'd get a backtrack clearance to pull back out onto the runway to taxi to the other end.  If it's not busy, the tower controller may give you a backtrack clearance as part of your landing clearance so you can land, turn around and proceed straight back.  The controller can't give a landing clearance to anyone else until you are clear.

In any case, the main thing is that you can't proceed back without permission from somebody.

Note that London City is now controlled [offsite](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-39960993) using special cameras and sensors, but it works the same way.

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict the quote from UK AIP posted by ymb1, which states that after landing runway 09 aircraft should backtrack immediately, NOT roll out to the turnaround bay.